# Shipping: UPS - Error 10001 The XML document is not well formed

Tags: shipping-methods, ups

I'm trying to setup UPS XML Configuration in Magento.
But the shipping_ups.log always tells me following error:

```
<Response>
    <TransactionReference>
        <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>
        <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
    </TransactionReference>
    <ResponseStatusCode>0</ResponseStatusCode>
    <ResponseStatusDescription>Failure</ResponseStatusDescription>
    <Error>
        <ErrorSeverity>Hard</ErrorSeverity>
        <ErrorCode>10001</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDescription>The XML document is not well formed</ErrorDescription>
    </Error>
</Response>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! The requested XML is actually valid but it turned out that certain characters in the UPS password broke the validation.

```
<AccessLicenseNumber>1234567890ABCE</AccessLicenseNumber>
<UserId>MYUSERID</UserId>
<Password>pass&word</Password>
```

In my case it was a '&' in password.