# UPS - Malformed XML on shipping rates request

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, php-7, ups

inside the shipping.log file i can see this error:

**The XML document is not well formed**

After some digging I see that my Auth information are not well encoded.
It works perfectly when I write them directly without actually using the **getConfigData()** function. Is there anything to do to have these information correctly encoded, without writing directly my login information inside my file?

Answer (score 0):

The requested XML is actually valid but it turned out that certain characters in the UPS password broke the validation.

```
<AccessLicenseNumber>1234567890ABCE</AccessLicenseNumber>
<UserId>MYUSERID</UserId>
<Password>pass&word</Password>
```

In my case it was a '&' in password.

[Shipping: UPS - Error 10001 The XML document is not well formed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93197/shipping-ups-error-10001-the-xml-document-is-not-well-formed)

https://www.pluginhive.com/knowledge-base/woocommerce-ups-shipping-plugin-print-label-xml-document-not-well-formed-error-code-10001/

Comment: I thought about this as well, but it happens on the three XML tags, even the one with only 'normal' char such as A B or C
I have something like this:
`<UserId>(��\\yM-��h�Ą�z4]�m�@���hl���</UserId>`